# Oracle SQL to bring out report query using case or pivot

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables.

Projects:

[image]

and
KPI:

[image]

I need to join both and derive a query that gives the result like:

[image]

So basically, kpi data of all projects , first column would be the threshold value  where kpi is Analysis and Active=A, Second column where kpi is Derivation and active =I.

Oracle 12c.

Comment: The logic for your transformation is not at all clear.

Comment: Do you want to have the Threshold values for each project having the lowest KPI number, for Analysis and Derivation, with both data in the same row for each project?

Comment: yes, that's rght

Answer (score 0):

Use a couple of CTE's (with clauses) to filter down each type into its own "table" and then join them together:

```
with k1 as
( select k.project_id, k.threshold as a_thresh
  from kpi k
  where k.name='Analysis'
),
k2 as 
( select k.project_id, k.threshold as d_thresh
  from kpi k
  where k.name='Derivation'
)
select p.project_ID, 
       p.projects,
       k1.a_thresh,
       k2.d_thresh
from projects p
left join k1 on p.project_id = k1.project_id
left join k2 on p.project_id = k2.project_id
```

Unsure how you want to handle the multiple entries per type, but this should  get you started